# XSLT Transformation Mapping

Tags: xslt-2.0

I want to transform the below source to target using XSLT, but unable to do so. Could you please help on it?

Source :

```
{
  "gp_number" : "56826526",
  "lineLevel" : [ {
    "Qty" : "4.00",
    "Rate" : "50.00"
  }, {
    "Qty" : "3.00",
    "Rate" : "25.00"
  } ]
}
```

Target:

```
{
  "gp_number" : "56826526",
  "AmountCal_line" : [ {
    "Qty" : "4.00",
    "Rate" : "50.00",
    "Amount" : "200.00"
  }, {
    "Qty" : "3.00",
    "Rate" : "25.00",
    "Amount" : "75.00"
  } ],
  "TotalAmount" : "275.00"
}
```

Comment: Where do you take the `Amount` values from?

Comment: Amount value will be derived from qty × rate

Comment: The only version of XSLT to support processing JSON, which your input sample seems to be, is the current version XSLT 3, as supported by current release of Saxon and Altova. However, you have tagged your question for some reasons as XSLT 2.0. Which XSLT processor are you going to use?

Comment: We are going to transform in integration level in soa , its support xslt 2.0 ,i am getting issue to derived the Total amount

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 3, as supported by current versions of SaxonJS (2.6 is the current version) or Saxon Java, SaxonC, Saxon .NET or SaxonCS, you can process JSON input (on the command line with option `-json`) and produce JSON output (with XDM maps and arrays being serialized with output method json):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>
   
    <xsl:template match=".">
      <xsl:sequence 
        select="map { 'gp_number' : ?gp_number,
                      'lineLevel' : array { ?lineLevel?* ! map:put(., 'Amount', xs:decimal(?Qty) * xs:decimal(?Rate)) },
                      'Total_Amount' : sum(?lineLevel?*!(xs:decimal(?Qty) * xs:decimal(?Rate)))
                }"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Example fiddle using SaxonJS 2](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Amap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Fmap%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22json%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20select%3D%22map%20%7B%20%27gp_number%27%20%3A%20%3Fgp_number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27lineLevel%27%20%3A%20array%20%7B%20%3FlineLevel%3F*%20%21%20map%3Aput%28.%2C%20%27Amount%27%2C%20xs%3Adecimal%28%3FQty%29%20*%20xs%3Adecimal%28%3FRate%29%29%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27Total_Amount%27%20%3A%20sum%28%3FlineLevel%3F*%21%28xs%3Adecimal%28%3FQty%29%20*%20xs%3Adecimal%28%3FRate%29%29%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22gp_number%22%20%3A%20%2256826526%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22lineLevel%22%20%3A%20%5B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22Qty%22%20%3A%20%224.00%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22Rate%22%20%3A%20%2250.00%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22Qty%22%20%3A%20%223.00%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22Rate%22%20%3A%20%2225.00%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%5D%0D%0A%7D&input-type=JSON).